# Difference between std::is_base_of and std::is_convertible

Tags: c++, templates

These two templates seem to yield the same results. What is the difference and when should we use which?

```
using namespace std;

class A {

};

class B : public A {

};

class C : public A {

};

int main()
{
    cout << boolalpha << is_convertible<B, A>::value << '\n';
    cout << boolalpha << is_base_of<A, B>::value << '\n';

    cout << boolalpha << is_convertible<B, C>::value << '\n';
    cout << boolalpha << is_base_of<C, B>::value << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

After running the program, I got

```
true
true
false
false
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to define some conversions between otherwise unrelated classes. Use `protected` or `private` inheritance. Or test them with basic types like `int` and `long`.

Comment: `double x = 1; int y = 1; assert(x == y);` Please explain why both `int` and `double` exist.

Comment: @Deduplicator`is_base_of` can only be applied to classes. Am I right?

Comment: @Einiemand [No.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of)

Comment: @Einiemand But `value` only can be `true` if both types are classes...

Comment: Another try: `struct S { operator std::string () { return ""; } }; std::cout << std::is_base_of<std::string, S>::value << std::is_convertible<S, std::string>::value;`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) and [`std::is_convertible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible).

Here are some of differences:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct anything_can_convert_to {
    // This constructor constructs from anything
    template<class T> anything_can_convert_to(T&&) {}
};

struct can_convert_to_anything {
    // This conversion operator can convert to anything
    template<class T> operator T() { return *static_cast<T*>(nullptr); }
};

struct cant_convert_to_base;

struct base {
    base(const cant_convert_to_base&) = delete;
};

struct public_derived : base {};

struct private_derived : private base {};

struct cant_convert_to_base : base {};

int main() {
#define IS_CONVERTIBLE(FROM, TO) static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<FROM, TO>)
#define IS_NOT_CONVERTIBLE(FROM, TO) static_assert(!std::is_convertible_v<FROM, TO>)
#define IS_BASE_OF(BASE, DERIVED) static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<BASE, DERIVED>)
#define IS_NOT_BASE_OF(BASE, DERIVED) static_assert(!std::is_base_of_v<BASE, DERIVED>)

    IS_CONVERTIBLE(int, long);
    IS_CONVERTIBLE(int, anything_can_convert_to);
    IS_CONVERTIBLE(can_convert_to_anything, int);
    IS_NOT_CONVERTIBLE(anything_can_convert_to, int);

    IS_CONVERTIBLE(public_derived, base);
    IS_NOT_CONVERTIBLE(private_derived, base);
    IS_NOT_CONVERTIBLE(cant_convert_to_base, base);


    IS_NOT_BASE_OF(int, long);
    IS_NOT_BASE_OF(int, anything_can_convert_to);

    IS_BASE_OF(base, public_derived);
    IS_BASE_OF(base, private_derived);
    IS_BASE_OF(base, cant_convert_to_base);
}
```

You'll realise that they are for two different things. `std::is_base_of<Base, Derived>` does exactly what it sounds like: Whether or not `Base` is the base class of `Derived`, in terms of inheritance. `std::is_convertible<From, To>` basically checks if:

```
To test = (expression of type From);
```

is well formed. For inheritance, this is mostly the case if `From` is a base class of `To`, but there are many other situations where this is the case (For example, with private inheritance, you can't convert to the base, but `std::is_base_of` still works.)